# How to get a value from the JSON provided?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the value of id from the following JSON array.

```
[
  {
    "SaveValues": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "allposition": {
          "x": -5.02046537399292,
          "y": 4.489554405212402
        },
        "allrotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0,
          "w": 1
        },
        "allscale": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1
        },
        "linepos0": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "linepos1": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "movetype": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "allposition": {
          "x": -4.485479354858398,
          "y": -4.903786659240723
        },
        "allrotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0,
          "w": 1
        },
        "allscale": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1
        },
        "linepos0": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "linepos1": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "movetype": 1
      }
    ],
    "NoteValues": [
      {
        "movenumber": 1,
        "notemsg": "Attack"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "SaveValues": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "allposition": {
          "x": -5.02046537399292,
          "y": 4.489554405212402
        },
        "allrotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0,
          "w": 1
        },
        "allscale": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1
        },
        "linepos0": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "linepos1": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "movetype": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "allposition": {
          "x": 2.780655860900879,
          "y": 4.399117469787598
        },
        "allrotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0,
          "w": 1
        },
        "allscale": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1
        },
        "linepos0": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "linepos1": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "movetype": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "allposition": {
          "x": -4.485479354858398,
          "y": -4.903786659240723
        },
        "allrotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0,
          "w": 1
        },
        "allscale": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1
        },
        "linepos0": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "linepos1": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "movetype": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "allposition": {
          "x": 2.153193712234497,
          "y": -4.7106828689575195
        },
        "allrotation": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0,
          "w": 1
        },
        "allscale": {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 1
        },
        "linepos0": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "linepos1": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "z": 0
        },
        "movetype": 2
      }
    ],
    "NoteValues": [
      {
        "movenumber": 2,
        "notemsg": "Defend"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Intitally I want to show only the "id" from the SaveValue[0] array then after a button click  then "id" from the SaveValue[1] array.

```
for (int i = 0;i<1;i++)
{
    Debug.Log("Jnode values count " + JNode[i]["SaveValues"].Count);
    for (int j = 0;j<JNode[i]["SaveValues"].Count;j++)
    {
        int id = JNode[i]["SaveValues"][j]["id"];
        Debug.Log("id values --- " + id);
    }
}
```

Actually I am creating the JSON file using the following class.How to retrieve it using the same JSON class is the issue.How to deserialize it.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerHandler 
    {
    public int id; 
    public Vector2 allposition;
    public Quaternion allrotation;
    public Vector2 allscale;

    public Vector3 linepos0;
    public Vector3 linepos1;
    public int movetype;


    public PlayerHandler(int ids,Vector2 allpos,Quaternion allrot,Vector2 allscal,Vector3 Line0,Vector3 Line1,int Moves)

    {
        this.id = ids;
        this.allposition = allpos;
        this.allrotation = allrot;
        this.allscale = allscal;
        this.linepos0 = Line0;
        this.linepos1 = Line1;
        this.movetype = Moves;
    }



}

    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayerMovement
    {
    public int movenumber;
    public string notemsg;

    public PlayerMovement(int Movenum,string Note)
    {
        this.movenumber = Movenum;
        this.notemsg = Note;

    }

    }
```

A bit confusing don't understand how to loop and get different(customized) values inside JSON.

Comment: I like to use: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json  -- As well as formatting to visualize the JSON better: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  -- But it seems you have a JArray to start with, and then you need to get inside that and get the first SaveValue JObject.  And then you can get the JProperty's inside of that object.

Comment: Is this a "fixed format" so that you could create a class to deserialize the JSON using Newtonsofts `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. If you really only need the `id` you could create a  data object that only contains the id. The loop would be easier to understand if you iterate through lists of objects instead of `JNode` and Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you created classes to represent your JSON, so you can deserialize it using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string json)`.
Then you can access your data using the properties.

If you only need the `SaveValues` and the value of `id` your classes can look like this:

```
class DataObject
{
     public PlayerHandler[] SaveValues { get; set; }
}
```

The code to iterate all `ids` within all `SaveValues`(`PlayerHandler`) would look like this:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataObject[]>(json);

foreach (var dataObject in deserialized)
{
      foreach (var playerHandler in dataObject.SaveValues)
      {
          var id = playerHandler.Id;
          //Do with Id whatever you want
          Debug.Log(id.ToString);
      }
}
```

<s>If you need other values from `SaveValue` you can just add properties to the `SaveValue` class.</s> *Obsolete due to Question changes.*

**Personally** I would almost always recommend to deserialize JSON into objects and then access the values instead of using JNode, JObject, etc. to improve the readability.

Comment: I have created this JSON file using a class to serialize it.I can use the same class to Deserialize it ?

Comment: Yes, if you already have a class that represents the data structure, you can (and should) use it for serialization and deserialization.

Comment: I am using SimpleJSON.. What is this JsonConvert?

Comment: `JsonConvert` is an easy way to serialize and deserialize JSON provided by [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm#JsonConvert). I am not familiar with `SimpleJSON` but I guess you can also use it to convert your JSON to objects.

Comment: var deserialize = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerHandler>(jsonLoadstring); In Unity JsonUtility is there.After loading the string how to get values and count from deserialize?

Comment: When you have deserialized the JSON you can access the values as shown in the answer. I will edit it, so it matches you classes. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201089/discussion-between-redfox-and-zyonneo).